# Email No body specified

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail, send-mail

Im trying to send email using **transportbuilder** but I'm getting this error.

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException): No body
>   specified Exception #1 (Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception): No body
>   specified

The template is already in and everything is already put in. Im using the following code to send email.

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
                    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE, 'store' => $storeId])
                    ->setTemplateVars($vars)
                    ->setFrom($sender)
                    ->addTo($email, $name)
                    ->getTransport();

                $transport->sendMessage();
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue is in template id.**.

*Template does not set properly.That why it is showing error.*

If you have define email from `email_templates.xml` then

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="[TEMPLATE_ID]" label="[TEMPLATE_ID]" file="[TemplateHTMLFILE].html" type="html" module="Vendor_Module" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

***Then, [TEMPLATE_ID] is template id*** you should it  at **`setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)`**

***Also,Change and try it***

> 'store' => $storeId

to

> \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID